# What is the correct approach to learn Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In the last 3 months, i have learnt html, css, js and php and now i'm trying to learn Framework Codeigniter. My teacher gave me a rough idea abt MVC and asked me to download a project made on codeigniter from  internet and edit it.

I downloaded a login form project and tried to read it. But i'm still kind of confused how everything works. i hv 2 questions:

1. What is the correct approach to learn codeigniter?
2. In how many days one can learn codeigniter? (i practice around 6-7 hrs a day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to learn codeigniter is to read the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) of codeigniter

Because, codeigniter framework is so much popular for their well formatted and clean documentation.

Or you can check [this](http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/) for beginner level tutorial

Or if you want to learn codeigniter by doing practical projects then you can follow this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/30-awesome-codeigniter-tutorials-for-all-skill-levels--net-16915)

Comment: +1 Good answer Hasib, However this kind of question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I learned CI over a weekend using this technique.

Start with simply setting up a 2 page site.
Home and About Us.
Pass simple string variables from the controllers to the views.

Next, bring a model into it.
Make a method in your model that returns some plain text, to the controller and finally to the model.

Next, make the model actually make a request to your database and return the result to the constructor then view.

After that try these:

- write a helper function
- Try making a basic route
- Log a debugging message
- upload a file from a form using the upload library

That's a good grounding in CI
Keep in mind Codeigniter is no longer in development also.
If your keen on sticking with PHP, you might want to check out the similar active project called "[Laravel](http://laravel.com/)" after getting the hang of CIs very simple MVC structure.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the common way is read their manual and follow the guide, the another approach is search youtube for codeigniter turial, there are many good tutorial out there and easy to follow for example here is my result in the first place for keyword "codeigniter tutorial" 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP9NRZXOvIw&list=PLIQyGVrcLTeXsq37O7IBGaUwu6xEwqBWV&index=1

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.